# Creating a bootable Mac OS USB from Ubuntu 20.04. Unetbootin won't install

Tags: boot, package-management, live-usb, macosx, unetbootin

I am trying to create a bootable usb drive for Mac OS El Capitan from a machine that has Ubuntu 20.04.

I have tried to install Unetbootin.

*sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin*

I received this installation message in the terminal:

*Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:*

*The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 unetbootin : Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installable
              Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not installable
              Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installable
              Recommends: extlinux but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: unetbootin-translations but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: gksu but it is not installable or
                          kdesudo but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.*

I am an Ubuntu novice, but I have used it on and off for the last 12 years. Are there any ways to fix this please?

Comment: If you have an El Capitan image, maybe try using the USB creator (just type `USB` in the dash) or try using Gnome Disks (`disks` in the dash). With Disks you can just select the flash drive and klick restore image.